# Error in extracting node value of xml. Error : Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed

Tags: xml, vb.net

I am trying to extract a value of a node in xml. I am facing some problems due to its name space. In below xml, I want the value of 'faultstring' tag.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
 <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
  <faultcode>Error</faultcode>
  <faultstring>Invalid combination of Username and Password.</faultstring>
  </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
 </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I am using following code to get the value. But it throws error.

```
Dim xmlDoc As New XmlDocument
    Dim namespaces As XmlNamespaceManager = New XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable)

    namespaces.AddNamespace("ns", "SOAP-ENV")
    xmlDoc.Load("SOAP.xml")
    Dim oNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("ns:Envelope/ns:Body/ns:Fault/faultstring")
    MsgBox(oNode.InnerXml.ToString)
```

I am not getting any solution. If anyone can help with this ! Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As i did not get any help on my question, I tried myself. The solution code goes as follows.

```
    Dim xmlDoc As New XmlDocument
    Dim namespaces As XmlNamespaceManager = New XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable)

    namespaces.AddNamespace("SOAP-ENV", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")
    xmlDoc.Load("SOAP.xml")

    Dim xPathString = "/SOAP-ENV:Envelope/SOAP-ENV:Body/SOAP-ENV:Fault/faultstring"
    Dim oNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(xPathString, namespaces)
```

It works fine now !! cheerss !!